# jOOQ always complains about "no suitable method found for createField" after successful generation

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I'm evaluating jOOQ `3.11.12` using Postgresql `12.0`. This is my (super) simple database:

```sql
--
-- INITIAL DATABASE SETUP
--
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";


--
-- CREATE STATEMENT(S)
--
CREATE TABLE departments
(
  id   UUID        NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT pk_department_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE employees
(
  id            UUID        NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  first_name    VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  last_name     VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,

  department_id UUID,

  CONSTRAINT pk_employee_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_employees_departments_id FOREIGN KEY (department_id) REFERENCES departments (id)
);


--
-- INSERT STATEMENT(S)
--
INSERT INTO departments(id, name)
VALUES ('945079360f314e93a749b1bd83e037bb', 'Clerical'),    -- 94507936-0f31-4e93-a749-b1bd83e037bb
       ('b2759d843e8549c397d9b0ce265c3312', 'Engineering'), -- b2759d84-3e85-49c3-97d9-b0ce265c3312
       ('cdd1781eb948411ca15f2dfe462ce247', 'Sales'); -- cdd1781e-b948-411c-a15f-2dfe462ce247
INSERT INTO departments(name)
VALUES ('Marketing');

INSERT INTO employees(first_name, last_name, department_id)
VALUES ('Charles', 'Rafferty', '945079360f314e93a749b1bd83e037bb'),
       ('Joe', 'Armstrong', 'b2759d843e8549c397d9b0ce265c3312'),
       ('Robert', 'Virding', 'b2759d843e8549c397d9b0ce265c3312'),
       ('Mike', 'Williams', 'b2759d843e8549c397d9b0ce265c3312'),
       ('Elizabeth', 'Heisenberg', 'cdd1781eb948411ca15f2dfe462ce247'),
       ('x80486', 'Williams', NULL);
```

I have a Spring Boot project that uses Flyway to setup the database (don't mind the data seed for now, e.g.: the `INSERT` statements), and for the code generation I'm using the `dev.bombinating.jooq-codegen` (Gradle) plugin version `3.12.1`:

```
id("dev.bombinating.jooq-codegen").version("3.12.1")

...

configure<JooqExtension> {
  val database = Database()
    .withExcludes("flyway_schema_history.*|information_schema.*|pg_catalog.*")
    .withIncludes(".*")
    .withInputSchema("public")
  val generate = Generate().withDeprecated(false)
    .withFluentSetters(false)
    .withImmutablePojos(false)
    .withRecords(false)
  val target = Target().withDirectory("${project.buildDir}/generated-sources/jooq/")
    .withPackageName("${project.group}.codegen") // io.shido.codegen
  val jooqVersion: String by project

  edition = JooqEdition.OpenSource
  generator = Generator().withDatabase(database)
    .withGenerate(generate)
    .withName("org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGenerator")
    .withStrategy(Strategy().withName("org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGeneratorStrategy"))
    .withTarget(target)
  jdbc = Jdbc().withDriver("org.postgresql.Driver")
    .withPassword("postgres")
    .withUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/kotlin_spring_boot_jooq")
    .withUser("postgres")
  version = jooqVersion
}

sourceSets { // TODO: dev.bombinating.jooq-codegen should configure this automatically with sane defaults
  main { java.srcDir("${buildDir.absolutePath}/generated-sources/jooq/") }
}
```

I can "resolve" (import) and use the generated types: `io.shido.codegen.tables.Departments.DEPARTMENTS`, but as soon as I try to run the application I get a bunch of errors like this:

```sh
/home/x80486/Workshop/Development/kotlin-spring-boot-jooq/build/generated-sources/jooq/io/shido/codegen/tables/Departments.java:61: error: no suitable method found for createField(Name,DataType<UUID>,Departments,String)
    public final TableField<Record, UUID> ID = createField(DSL.name("id"), org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.UUID.nullable(false).defaultValue(org.jooq.impl.DSL.field("uuid_generate_v4()", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.UUID)), this, "");

...

/home/x80486/Workshop/Development/kotlin-spring-boot-jooq/build/generated-sources/jooq/io/shido/codegen/tables/Departments.java:66: error: no suitable method found for createField(Name,DataType<String>,Departments,String)
    public final TableField<Record, String> NAME = createField(DSL.name("name"), org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.VARCHAR(20).nullable(false), this, "");
```

> **NOTE:** I get pretty much the same result(s) if I do `.withExcludes("")` also.

...and also I'm getting some other errors, but those are probably related with the way I set up the plugin settings (I guess):

```sh
W o.j.m.AbstractDatabase    - SQL exception            : Exception while executing meta query: ERROR: column c.consrc does not exist
  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "c.conkey" or the column "c.conbin".
  Position: 127
```

Is there any way to get around this? I've seen that most of the examples out there put the generated code in `sourceSets["main"]`, but I think it should behave the same in the way I configured it.

> **IMPORTANT:** The `jOOQ` artifact is provided by `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq` (inferred from the `2.1.9.RELEASE` Spring BOM).

Comment: The jOOQ version in spring-boot-starter-jooq is 3.11.12, while you use codegen version 3.12.1 according to `id("dev.bombinating.jooq-codegen").version("3.12.1")`. We should ensure they are in the exact same version. Also, is `dev.bombinating.jooq-codegen` the official codegen lib?

Comment: ...aaaaannd you are correct: the version mismatch was the issue. I thought about changing it initially, but never did it...I was like: nah, it can't be, one is `3.11.x` and the other one is `3.12.x`, what could go wrong there :troll_face: ...if you put that as an answer I'll accept it :thumbs:up:

Comment: Not specific to this particular plugin, but when using Spring Boot, it is always a good idea to be sure to specify the *exact* jOOQ version, and possibly edition / distribution, overriding that provided by Spring Boot: https://blog.jooq.org/2019/06/26/how-to-use-jooqs-commercial-distributions-with-spring-boot/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jOOQ version in spring-boot-starter-jooq (spring boot release 2.1.9) is 3.11.12, while you use codegen version 3.12.1 according to `id("dev.bombinating.jooq-codegen").version("3.12.1")`. We should ensure they are in the exact same version.

You could also use spring boot release 2.2.0 that comes with jOOQ version=3.12.1.